# Unable to load jars in a Rails app on Glassfish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glassfish, jruby

I have a Rails app that I'm trying to deploy onto Glassfish using the Glassfish gem, but it's unable to load the jar files I've written.  I've tried passing the jars' path to jruby explicitly with jruby -I, but no luck.  Any tips?  Thanks a bunch

Comment: Have you tried explicitly requiring the jars :

require '/path/to/myjar.jar'

Answer (score 1):

I think if you put your jars in the lib directory of your jruby install they'll automatically be picked up in your classpath.